# Hamcrest assert complex object with List member

Tags: java, testing, junit, hamcrest

If I have a POJO class

```
  @Value
  @AllArgsConstructor
  class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final List<Address> addresses;
  }
```

As you can see, the object contains a List. In my unit tests, it is hard to assert on this since the ordering is not known of the addresses (or any other potential List/Set/Map property of Person).

How can I do the assertion without changing the equals method of the Person class and make sure the ordering of addresses is ignored? I'm looking for something like

```
assertThat(actualPerson, is(expectedPerson).ignoreOrderingOf("addresses"));
```

What I mean is that the *ordering* of `actualPerson.addresses` and `expectedPerson.addresses` should be ignored in the assertion.

What testing strategy should I use in general to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the addresses separately like this:

```
assertThat(actualPerson, samePropertyValuesAs(expectedPerson, "addresses"))
assertThat(actualPerson.addresses, containsInAnyOrder(expectedPerson.addresses))
```

The first assertion will compare all properties except the addresses, and the second one will compare the addresses while ignoring the order.

Comment: I'm on Hamcrest 1.3, and the ignoredProperties parameter does not exist there, but I think I can upgrade. Thank you for that idea!